# How to end / kill a function that checks for IP addresses inside a table without affecting other functions

Tags: php

According to the title, how can I accomplish it? One of the function that checks for IP addresses which are already stored in db should kill the specific check function without affecting others.I used to use exit() and die() but it stops all functions.

main.php:

```
function CheckIfUserIpExist() {
    $connection = DBconnect();
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM views WHERE user_ip = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_ip);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $users_ip = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($users_ip > 0) {
        die();
    }
}

function AddUserWhenPageIsViewed() {
    $connection = DBconnect();
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $time_ = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO views (user_ip, time_) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_ip, $time_);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Index.php

```
CheckIfUserIpExist(); 
AddUserWhenPageIsViewed();
```

Regards.

Comment: Use return statement

Comment: In your first function, use return ($users_ip > 0). if (CheckIfUserIpExist() === false) { ddUserWhenPageIsViewed(); } So ip will not be inserted if already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to return a status from your Check function

```
function CheckIfUserIpExist() {
    $connection = DBconnect();
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM views WHERE user_ip = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_ip);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $users_ip = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($users_ip > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function AddUserWhenPageIsViewed() {
    $connection = DBconnect();
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $time_ = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO views (user_ip, time_) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_ip, $time_);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Then when you call the test function you know what to do next. If you get true the user exists so dont call the Add function, if you get false, the user did not exist, so create one.

```
if ( ! CheckIfUserIpExist() ) { 
    AddUserWhenPageIsViewed();
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for, thank you! :) I appreciate all suggestions and answers!

Comment: Lol yeah, I forgot about that feature to approve it, my apologies, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

return is what you need

```
function CheckIfUserIpExist() {
    $connection = DBconnect();
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM views WHERE user_ip = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_ip);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $users_ip = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($users_ip > 0) {
        return;
    }
}

function AddUserWhenPageIsViewed() {
    $connection = DBconnect();
    $user_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $time_ = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO views (user_ip, time_) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user_ip, $time_);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```